# “incomplete type is not allowed” & “member function declared with ‘override’ does not override a base class member” in blank UE 5.3 project

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine5

started blank project (named SampleShooter) and created a c++ character but it gives me this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details

Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  SampleShooter   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers\StringView.h    408     

Error (active)  E0070   incomplete type is not allowed  SampleShooter   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Containers\StringView.h    415     

Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with ‘override’ does not override a base class member  SampleShooter   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   157     

Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with ‘override’ does not override a base class member  SampleShooter   C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Serialization\ArchiveProxy.h   167
```

the header file named BaseCharacter.h is this:

```
#pragma once

include “CoreMinimal.h”
include “GameFramework/Character.h”
include “BaseCharacter.generated.h”

UCLASS()
class SAMPLESHOOTER_API ABaseCharacter : public ACharacter
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public:
// Sets default values for this character’s properties
ABaseCharacter();

protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public:
// Called every frame
virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

// Called to bind functionality to input
virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

};
```

the cpp file named BaseCharacter.cpp is this:

```
include “BaseCharacter.h”

// Sets default values
ABaseCharacter::ABaseCharacter()
{
// Set this character to call Tick() every frame. You can turn this off to improve performance if you don’t need it.
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ABaseCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void ABaseCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void ABaseCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

}
```

i dont see any include mistakes and the code should work.
sounds like he had the same problem:

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/incomplete-type-is-not-allowed/114700

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/incomplete-type-is-not-allowed/431166

https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/unable-to-compile-blank-project/1214010

**…is there any other solution besides ignoring it by using build only ?**

Comment: Looks like a class `SampleShooter` is forward declared, but not defined. Take a look at your sources (also autogenerated headers) and try to find where this class is defined. Then include the header with the definition.

Comment: please post a [mcve]. `include “BaseCharacter.h”` is cetainly not the code you compiled, we dont know what else you modified compared to the actual code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai every time i create a blank project with "Quixel Bridge" and "Visual Studio Integration Tool" as plugin. then i go to Edit-> plugins, on Unreal Editor, to enable the “new” visual studio plugin. then i go to tools -> create c++ class . . . and create a public character named BaseCharacter. go to VS22 and get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error in Visual Studio, then I decided to switch to Rider and it told that build is failing because Live Coding console is launched (though I didn't have UE opened). Then I restarted my computer to kill live console and managed to build.

I guess it's just VS not being able to give correct error message, when it's raised by UnrealBuildTool, try switching tabs to see the actual log with UBT error.

Comment: this could explain why it was suddenly working again.. | i dont know who or why someone gave you an downvote, middle finger to stack overflow elites i guess